# How to use bookmarklet to open multi-links in clipboard?

Tags: javascript, browser, bookmarklet

In my notepad there are three links:

`https://www.google.com https://www.bing.com https://www.yahoo.com`

How to onekey open multi-links in clipboard?

i know that there are a lot of extensions to make it happen.

Is there a "bookmarklet" way?

Thanks in advance.

Is it possiable to use regex in bookmarklet?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use a regex if you need to (as in the code). In fact anything that executes in console can be re-worked as a bookmarklet.

Do you know how to **make a bookmarklet**? You can just **save any page as a bookmark** in your browser, and then **replace its URL for the code** in a specific format.

As for the question, I suppose that you wish to copy the links from a notepad, click the bookmarklet, paste the links, press enter and get all the links opened. Here is the solution:

**I). Whitespace as a delimiter**

1). To open links you can save this bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function(){
    /*prompt asks for the links delimited by whitespaces*/
    var linksWithDelim = window.prompt('Insert links, with delimiters');

    /*getting rid of extra spaces, with simple regex in replace*/
    linksWithDelim = linksWithDelim.trim().replace(/ +/g, ' ');
    var arrOfLinks = [];

    /*links from prompt go to the array splited by the delimiter*/
    arrOfLinks = linksWithDelim.split(' ');

    /*the loop opens each link from the array*/
    for (i=0; i<arrOfLinks.length; i++){
        window.open(arrOfLinks[i]);
    }
})();
```

2). As an input you can use your

`https://www.google.com https://www.bing.com https://www.yahoo.com`

Make sure the links have proper protocol like `https://` and proper whitespaces.

**II). New line as a delimiter**

If your notepad contains the links delimited with new line breaks instead of whitespaces, you might replace the correspoding line of the code for

`arrOfLinks = linksWithDelim.split('\n');`

After changing that line the input like

```
https://www.google.com
https://www.bing.com
https://www.yahoo.com
```

copy-pasted to the prompt is supposed to work as well.